# Gradle fails on manifest merging for "targetApi"

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My project contains activity declarations in the manifest that use the `tools:targetApi` attribute to ignore some warnings. Specifically:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProtocolActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_protocols"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.InformationActivity"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.InformationActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Out of the blue, however, for instance after switching branches, I get the following compilation error:

> Error:/home/paul/git/ally-v2-app/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:67:9-80:20:
>   Error: Invalid instruction 'targetApi', valid instructions are :
>   REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT
>   ...
>   Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No
>   enum constant com.android.manifmerger.AttributeOperationType.TARGETAPI

I'm using the following:

- Gradle 2.10
- Gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta6
- Android Studio 2.0 beta 6
- Both on an Ubuntu 15.10 machine and a Windows 10 machine

It seems I can get things working again by clearing the cache and restarting Android Studio, or removing the attributes, building, then adding them again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replacing it by

```
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
```

also *fixes* the lint issue.

Comment: is there something that can be done when the tools:targetApi comes from an external library manifestFile without modifying it?

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `targetApi` tag:

```
tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"
```