# Android: targetApi not recognized in the manifest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, lint

I have the following line in my manifest:

```
<intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true">
```

but I get a lint warning:

```
Attribute autoVerify is only used in API 23 and higher (current min is 16)
```

so I changed it to look like this (as per the recommendation that android studio gives me):

```
<intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="M">
```

and I then receive this error when building the apk:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: [path_to_manifest]/AndroidManifest.xml:58:13-67:29: Error: Invalid instruction 'targetApi', valid instructions are : REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.android.manifmerger.AttributeOperationType.TARGETAPI
```

How can I get rid of this error while still getting rid of the lint warning?

Edit:
I tried both "clean project" and "invalidate cache and restart" - neither work to solve the error.

Issue opened on the Issue Tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211805

Comment: That sounds like a bug, you should report it here: http://tools.android.com/filing-bugs

Comment: Thanks - I've filed an issue on this.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211805

Comment: Has this bug been fixed? How will an application work on API before 23? I built an app and didn't get any exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844427/gradle-fails-on-manifest-merging-for-targetapi) the gives a workaround for this issue.

By using the line:

```
<intent-filter  android:autoVerify="true"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

The lint error is solved and the apk can be built. I'm not going to mark this as the accepted answer though - I prefer if someone can explain how targetApi can be used (if it can be used)?

Answer (score -1):

Proper syntax is

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about. `targetApi` is entirely different from `*SdkVersion`.